# Are there any alternatives to getting a bitmap from XML other than using BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, alias, bitmapdrawable

I'm currently using BitmapDrawable in my app, but unfortunately, this implementation seems somewhat broken in Lollipop (It worked OK prior to LP, there's a separarte question regarding that issue).

So, OK, I have an XML file which is basically this:

**backgrounds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/backgrounds_xlarge" />
```

The above is an XML file (Alias), that points to an actual png file.

In my code I'm getting the bitmap like this:

**Code**

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgrounds);
backgrounds = bd.getBitmap();
```

This question is to ask if there is an alternative way to get this bitmap?  Please note that BitmapFactory is no good to me as I *must* be able to get this bitmap via the xml alias shown above.

I've read the [Offical docs on creating XML Aliases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) but unfortunately, they are somewhat lacking when it comes to explaining how to get access to the bitmap.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to get a `Bitmap` from a `BitmapDrawable`, using a `Canvas`:

```
    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) view.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgrounds);
    Bitmap backgrounds = Bitmap.createBitmap(bd.getIntrinsicWidth(), bd.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(backgrounds); 
    bd.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    bd.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Thanks for this @samgak - this does indeed create the bitmap, unfortunately, I still get the same problem, I'll open another question for that, but your answer provided the solution to the question asked - so, accepted, thanks!